# imagemagic: how to split an image vertically based on aspect ratio and also with a vertical overlap

Tags: imagemagick

I have lot of images and not i want to split them w.r.t aspect ratio.

What is presently working is

```
convert -crop 2:1 input.png cropped_%d.png
```

The above command split the image. Assuming i have 900px x 2000px then it creates 5 images.

But now the problem is i want to keep some overlap

I tried

```
convert -crop 2:1+0+40 input.png cropped_%d.png
```

Its only giving one image.

I tried

```
convert -crop 1x4+0+40@ Settings_commit1.png cropped_%d.png
```

This works well. But here i have to mention 1x4 (grid). But I want to do it by aspect ratio

Comment: Aspect crop as 2:1 was intended to give only one resulting image. It was not intended to crop into multiple pieces. Also you should read the input before -crop command. I am not sure when the behavior changed to split images and will have to check whether this was intentional or not.

Comment: i dont know when but it works like that in my system

Comment: My mistake. It only crops one result when you add +X+Y. There is no option for overlap cropping with -crop other than looping and computing the overlap for +X+Y. But you can do aspect computations inline for the ratio and compute the offset for overlap also when using Imagemagick 7. Otherwise, you have to precompute variables. I have an overlapcrop script at my web site, http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php, but it was written before aspect cropping was added to Imagemagick. So that is not an option in it currently.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following way

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-35 Q16 x86_64 2019-03-25 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib heic jbig jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

The two commands split the image:

Based on aspect ratio split the image file (but overlap does not work 2:1+0+40)

```
convert -crop 2:1 input.png cropped_%d.png
```

Based on grid split the image file and overlap works (+0+40)

```
convert -crop 1x4+0+40@ Settings_commit1.png cropped_%d.png  (with 40px vertical overlap)
```

Logic is we get the number of split images from aspect ratio and then use it in grid

This is the scrip which worked

```
filename="someimage.png";
# just creating a dir and empty it 
mkdir ~/croped
rm -rf ~/croped/*
# split the image base on aspect ratio and save them in croped folder
convert -crop 903:600 ${filename} ~/croped/crop_aspect_%d.png;
# count the number of files in the croped folder
number_files=`ls -l ~/croped | grep -E "crop_aspect_*" | wc -l`
# based on this number apply the grid
convert -crop 1x${number_files}+0+8@ ${filename} ~/croped/crop_grid_%d.png
```